# Max width of CSS button with margin property

Tags: css

I'm trying to utilize `max-width` on a button with a `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `28px`.

When my site is shrunk down for mobile, this button still retains its margins and carries over off-screen. How can I fix this?

Here's my CSS for the button:

```
.button {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #5094CF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 28px 0 28px;
}
```

Comment: what is your current screen and what is the expected screen? Please provide us with fiddle...

Comment: You can fix it with the media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need mediaqueries for all resolutions you need, for example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
      margin:  0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .box {
      margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Different margins depending on the resolution of the client.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

There's a pleasantly easy fix for your issue, try this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 658px) { // for mobile devices 
    .button{
        // your preferred styling properties for displaying in mobile devices
     }
}
```